# Algorithm detect simple curves using Voronoi diagram or Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, computational-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm, voronoi-diagram

I wonder if there is algorithm/method to determine if [closed](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedCurve.html) (or even non closed) curve is [simple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleCurve.html) or not, using the mathematics from the field of computational geometry? Especially I wonder if exist solution using [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) or [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)?

I'm not the strongest math man but from some reason I thought about it and it seems possible.

Example demonstrating the issue is [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284650/how-to-determine-if-set-of-ordered-coordinates-form-a-simple-curve).

Thanks,